# Chaiscript #include statement mapping in biicode.conf

Tags: c++, biicode, chaiscript

I want to create a biicode block that depends on the chaiscript block (lefticus/ChaiScript). If I include the chaiscript headers this way

```
#include <lefticus/ChaiScript/chaiscript/chaiscript.hpp>
```

`bii find` works fine. But I would like to include them as

```
#include <chaiscript/chaiscript.hpp>
```

so I changed my `biicode.conf` such as this :

```
[includes]
    chaiscript/*.hpp: lefticus/ChaiScript
```

but then I got

```
florian@florian-VirtualBox:~/dev/ATE$ bii find
INFO: Processing changes...
WARN: There are local unresolved dependencies
They will not be searched in the server
Unresolved: chaiscript/chaiscript.hpp, chaiscript/chaiscript_stdlib.hpp
INFO: Finding missing dependencies in server
INFO: Looking for chaiscript/utility...
WARN: Can't find block candidate for: chaiscript/utility
INFO: Looking for chaiscript/dispatchkit...
WARN: Can't find block candidate for: chaiscript/dispatchkit
INFO: No block candidates found
```

How do I have to configure biicode to make it work with the "classic" chaiscript includes ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were doing well but you need to write the requirement too:

```
[requirements] 
     lefticus/ChaiScript: 1
[includes]
     chaiscript/*.hpp: lefticus/ChaiScript
```

This way you can keep your includes as:

```
#include "chaiscript/chaiscript.hpp"
```

PD: it is necessary because "bii find" don't work yet with such include mapping.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think I've done this test, and the `bii find` used to delete the `[requirements]` content saying that it was not used. Maybe I forgot to do something... I wil test it when I got home tonight !

Comment: FYI, I've added a ChaiScript organization, for the official repository from here: http://www.biicode.com/ChaiScript/ChaiScript

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the solution. The `[includes]` tag in the `biicode.conf` file only works when the dependencies are already existant. I had to modify my code to include files with the full path to the block :

```
#include <lefticus/ChaiScript/chaiscript/chaiscript.hpp>
```

and launch `bii deps` before adapting the `biicode.conf` file.

Comment: I'm still testing the biicode for ChaiScript support, I had not intended / expected anyone to be using it yet. There's no question it needs work still.

Comment: I was using Chaiscript for a personal project for some time, and when I saw that it was on biicode, I thought it was time to do the same ! But I did not have the time to test the code with your Chaiscript block...